# How does facebook select image to display on timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any criteria to  how Facebook  selects an image.

1. the FB share dialogue  choose the  same  avator image from page
   regardless of  what post  we are sharing  from  page
2. when the post is shared on FB timeline   -  FB  is grabbing our mobile  logo

see  here  for  visual

https://goo.gl/6Gw6t1

So can we control  the  image  that FB  posts on the timeline when  a share  is  made?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the appropriate meta tags on your page if you want to instruct Facebook to use specific assets.

Take a look at the information on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags)

> **Use proper Open Graph tags**
>
> When someone shares content from your site to Facebook, our crawler will scrape the HTML of the URL that is shared. On a regular HTML page this content is basic and may be incorrect, because the scraper has to guess which content is important, and which is not.
>
> Take control of what the Facebook crawler picks up from each page by using Open Graph meta tags. These tags provide structured info about the page such as the title, description, preview image, and more.

---

While you are testing and changing the content on your page, you can use Facebook's very useful [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to find out exactly how Facebook see's your page and what elements are used.

Remember that Facebook heavily caches content such as this, so when you make changes, be sure to run the URL though the debugger in order to refresh Facebook's cache of your page.

Answer (score 1):

If you use properly defined OpenGraph tags, then the behavior should be consistent.

See the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/checklist

Furthermore, use the URL Debugger to see what FB crawls from your page:

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Thank you for  the  perfect  answers