# Playing content on facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, youtube, facebook-opengraph

previously i believed an OG meta tag was what i should be looking into but now i'm really not sure. How do I share a video from youtube so that it will play on a users timeline (this doesn't happen on a phone). Please help I'm very confused

Comment: What is the issue with OG meta tag?

Comment: I just don't know what I'm doing. If i click share under a video, what do I do next?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should start reading the docs. This question is much too broad. To get started, have a look on my answer at

- [How does facebook select image to display on timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702555/how-does-facebook-select-image-to-display-on-timeline/31702691#31702691)

Comment: I've already watched tutorials on that though. I want to be able to play a video on a timeline as if it were embedded from youtube. There's gotta be a way to do that?

Comment: You need to use the correct OpenGraph tags for your content. It's all in the docs.

Comment: @Tobi your answer is very unfair. Clearly the lad is just  confused.

Comment: @user61026 I don't think so. This question is much too broad for StackOverflow. I think 2mins of using Google is not too much effort, he could have easily found an answer himself.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you would like to do something along these lines:

```
<head>
 <meta property="og:video" content="video link"/>
</head>
```

then add a share button to share the page via a facebook share dialog.

When the shared page is loaded by facebook the og meta tags will tell facebook what information to show.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://your swebpage">share on facebook</a>
```

If you want to add meta data dynamically maybe use Jquery to fire off a function like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
 $('head').append( '<meta property="og:video" content="video link"/>' );
});
```

Comment: Adding tags dynamically makes no sense. The scraping is done server-sided, and JS is not interpreted by the FB scraper.

Comment: For sure, but the idea is that you 'could' add meta tags dynamically. Perhaps manipulate a template before rendering the page using NodeJS and the Jade / Hogan templating engines. OR use PHP. @Tobi as I mentioned this is a guide. At least my answer was somewhat more helpful than yours!!

Comment: You **cannot** create OpenGraph tags on the client side so that the FB scraper picks them up. Well, you 'could' do that, but it would be useless. And that's what you suggested. If you're suggesting something on the server-side, you should also write that. And, to be clear, the question is against the conduct here at StackOverflow. If you don't believe me, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Tobi. The fact that you have marked my question as a dublicate to a completely different question tells me you don't really understand what I'm trying to achieve. I'm not interested in customizing a link. Choosing a picture and suitable message to go alongside a link - NO! I want to be able to pull the video into facebook or at least have it appear that way

Comment: @cheffernan087 apologies. I'll have a think about this.